# The best way to fill varray in different code blocks pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

Usually I fill arrays like this:

```
TYPE name_options IS VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR2(300);
dd_name_options_c name_options;

dd_name_options_c := name_options(string1, string2, string3, string4);
```

But what if I have two blocks that generate strings and I want to save all the strings to one array:

```
-- Block 1
....
dd_name_options_c := name_options(string1, string2, string3, string4);
....
-- Block 2
....
dd_name_options_c := name_options(string5, string6);
```

So, in the end, the array will contain 6 strings:
string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `extend`

```
declare
  TYPE name_options IS VARRAY(6) OF VARCHAR2(300);
  dd_name_options_c name_options;

begin
  dd_name_options_c := name_options('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

  dd_name_options_c.Extend(2);
  dd_name_options_c(5) := 'e';
  dd_name_options_c(6) := 'f';

  dbms_output.put_line(dd_name_options_c.count());
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

> what if I have two blocks that generate strings and I want to save all the strings to one array

If the blocks are separate program units or otherwise disconnected, maybe even can be executed in different orders, you need some logic which can tell whether the target array is already populated. One solution is to use a (private) PL/SQL procedure to manage this.

```
procedure populate_varray 
     ( p_tgt in out name_options
       , p_new in name_options)
is
   n pls_integer;
begin
   if p_tgt is null 
         or p_tgt.count() = 0 
   then
     p_tgt := p_new;
   elsif  p_new is not null 
         and p_new.count() > 0
   then 
     n := p_tgt.count();
     for idx in 1 .. p_new.count() loop
       p_tgt.extend();
       p_tgt(n + idx) := p_new(idx);
     end loop;
   end if;
end populate_varray;
```

Note: untested code, please comment below if there are errors :)

You would call it like this:

```
-- Block 1
....
populate_varray ( dd_name_options_c 
                  , name_options(string1, string2, string3, string4));
....
-- Block 2
....
populate_varray (dd_name_options_c  
                  , name_options(string5, string6) );
```

Comment: Thank you. It might be helpful in the near future. By now my blocks are pretty much connected.

Comment: in a loop I prefer to use something like this `p_tgt.last()` as an index after extending

Comment: @hotfix - fair enough. I can't remember the last time I used a VARRAY in real life (as opposed to Stack overflow). Nested tables are much better to work with; for instance we could easily solve this problem with MULTISET UNION.